# PHP : Obtain common values in 2 huge arrays

Tags: php, array-intersect

I have 2 arrays, Array **A** and **B** respectively . Array **A** contains ~300,000 string records, e.g.

```
[0] => 'apple',
[1] => 'pineapple',
[2] => 'orange',
...
[299,999] => 'banana'
```

while Array B contains 100,000 string values, e.g.

```
[0] => 'bamboo',
[1] => 'banana',
[2] => 'boy',
[3] => 'ball',
[4] => 'balloon',
[5] => 'bazooka',
```

The question is, how to find out the common values between 2 arrays ?

[array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) seems a promising function, but I worry about the performance. Is it better to convert the 2 arrays into text file, and do file-based compare? or am I worrying too much?

Codes to use `array_intersect()`:

```
$result_array = array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB);
```

Comment: Have you tested to see what performance might be?

Comment: If you have two arrays, `array_intersect` is probably the most efficient way to find the intersection. Writing them to files doesn’t really make much sense.

Comment: Unless you're planning to rely on the OS's diff command (assuming it's available) array_intersect should be your best bet

Comment: https://ignite.io/code/513e9afcec221ebe52000000 Seems quick enough?

Comment: yes, `array_intersect()` is the choice! completed the operation in less than 1 second.

Comment: indeed it is the best solution. writting you data in file will take more time than processing data in memory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result based on my own test, `array_intersect()` is the choice. It can produce the result in less than 1 second, as its efficiency is `O(n·log n)`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6329494/188331

Answer (score -1):

array_intersect function will be used for retrieving common values across arrays

But as array size is huge you need to specify configuration in script for execution with concern to performance

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

The above code snippet will respectively set the execution time limit to infinity and increasing memory limit will allocate more memory required to hold large sized array

Comment: If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it. A total of ~400,000 strings of about that length is only going to be about 28MB.

Comment: @minitech - If it ain't broke, try try again. Then walk away slowly. No one will know.

Comment: @minitech: 38.5Mb for me here, and doesn't change until the string became *really long* (`$o = memory_get_usage(true);

$a = array_fill(0, 300000, 'apple');

var_dump((memory_get_usage(true) - $o) / 1024 / 1024);`)