# How to get common values from two different arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with some user-id

```
$array1 = array("5","26","38","42");

$array2 = array("15","36","38","42");
```

What I need is, I need the common values from the array as follows

```
$array3 = array(0=>"38", 1=>"42");
```

I have tried **`array_intersect()`**. I would like to get a method that takes a minimum time of execution. Please help me, friends.

Comment: `array_intersect()` is still your best option.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: What's wrong with `array_intersect`? It can't possibly be too slow?

Comment: This might help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329211/php-array-intersect-efficiency/6329494#6329494

Comment: Good luck: http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php

Comment: [Here's how `array_intersect` is implemented](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#php_array_intersect) and [here's how it's called internally](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#3280). Try to improve algorithm for better performance.

Comment: Could any one please tell me why my question get vote down??? i just want to know is there any other better function for the same.
Thanks all of you who response to my question... :)

Comment: Dunno why everyone down voted this seems pretty fair what you asking

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Native PHP functions are faster than trying to build your own algorithm.

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: is there I can loop through the values of $result?
I understand that the $result variable will give me an array of key value pairs...but now I only want the values, not the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Use this one, though this maybe a long method:

```
$array1 = array("5","26","38","42");

$array2 = array("15","36","38","42");

$final_array = array();

foreach($array1 as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($val,$array2)){
        $final_array[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Result: Array ( [0] => 38 [1] => 42 )

Comment: can you suggest a reason why your answer is better choice over array_intersect...

Answer (score 2):

array_intersect() works just fine.

> array array_intersect ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $ ... ]
> )

```
$array1 = array("5","26","38","42");

$array2 = array("15","36","38","42");

echo array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

https://www.php.net/array_intersect

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `$key=>$value` to your problem so check this answer:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("5", "26", "38", "42");
$array2 = array("15", "36", "38", "42");

foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $array2)) {
        $array3[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($array3);
?>
```