# PHP : How to get common values from different array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays as follows:-

```
$a = ["2","11","6"];
$b = ["6","7"];
$c = array_diff($a, $b);

$c = ["2","11"];
```

The result in `$c` is wrong. I want the result should be as `$c = [6]`

in other words i want the common elements in both array be returned! but it is giving wrong error. Kindly help me?

Comment: So you want to use `array_intersect()`.

Comment: Your title says you're looking for the difference, you're using the function to get the difference... but you want the ones that _aren't_ different? O_o

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648962/how-to-get-common-values-from-two-different-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_intersect()`

```
$a = ["2","11","6"];
$b = ["6","7"];
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
```

**Demo: https://eval.in/682653**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = ["2","11","6"];
$b = ["6","7"];
$c = array_intersect($a,$b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_intersect (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
<?php
$a = ["2","11","6"];
$b = ["6","7"];
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);

print_r($c)

?>
```