# return an array of numbers that show up in all three sub arrays

Tags: php, php-7

I want to compare all the sub arrays in the $ids and I want to return only the numbers that show up in all three arrays, so it would return 3 and 4 as an array.

```
$ids = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,4],
    [3,4,5],
];
```

expecting it to return

```
array(3,4)
```

UPDATE: My apologies, I left out the detail that I would not know how many arrays would be in the associative array, it could be 2 sub arrays, other times it could be 5. I appreciate all the answers I have received.

Comment: Not a duplicate, I am trying to compare a multi associate array, the one you linked to is a normal array.

Comment: I would have thought that working with 2 arrays is a short extension to what is in effect 3 arrays.  The end result is exactly what the duplicate indicated - `array_intersect()`.

Comment: @NigelRen: I agree in a way, however you would need to use `array_intersect($ids[0], $ids[1], $ids[2])` assuming that you know there are 3 elements, and that they are integer indexes and that they are consecutive from 0.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I thought duplicates weren't necessarily a case of *cut and paste* the answer - sometimes you will need to adapt it to your particular scenario.  The 2 answers both provide ways of applying `array_intersect()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously `array_intersect` is the solution [How to get common values from two different arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648962/how-to-get-common-values-from-two-different-arrays-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1).  If you know the number of sub-arrays and their indexes then it's as simple as:

```
$result = array_intersect($ids[0], $ids[1], $ids[2]);
```

However, if you need to do it for an unknown/variable number of sub-arrays and/or unknown indexes, use `$ids` as an array of arguments with `call_user_func_array`:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $ids);
```

Or better use [Argument unpacking via ...](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (PHP >= 5.6.0):

```
$result = array_intersect(...$ids);
```

Comment: And if you want to re-key: `array_values(array_intersect(...$ids));`

Comment: I should of provided more details, I failed to mention that the associative array would  not have a known amount of arrays in it, it is being dynamically created so it could have 2 arrays one time, and 5 the next time it is ran.

Answer (score 2):

Splice out the first subarray and then loop the rest and use array_intersect to filter the result to `3,4`.

```
$res = array_splice($ids,0,1)[0];

foreach($ids as $id){
    $res = array_intersect($res, $id);
}

var_dump($res); // 3,4
```

https://3v4l.org/Z7uZK

Comment: thanks! call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array); works as well, thanks

Comment: That is more or less the same thing. But yes.