# PHP: in_array() vs array_intersect() performance

Tags: php, arrays, performance, benchmarking, array-intersect

What, and how much, is faster - manually iterating over an array with `foreach` and checking for `needle` occurrence with `in_array()`, or using `array_intersect()`?

Comment: this answer might helpful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329211/php-array-intersect-efficiency

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Benchmark

**Test Script**

```
<?php
$numbers = range(32, 127);
$numbersLetters = array_map('chr', $numbers);

for (;;) {
    $numbersLetters = array_merge($numbersLetters, $numbersLetters);

    if (count($numbersLetters) > 10000) {
        break;
    }
}

$numbers = range(1, count($numbersLetters));

printf("Sample size: %d elements in 2 arrays (%d total) \n", count($numbers), count($numbers) + count($numbersLetters));
printf("Benchmarking speed in foreach + in_array() scenario... (this might take a while) ");

shuffle($numbers);
shuffle($numbersLetters);

$t1 = microtime(true);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if (in_array($number, $numbersLetters)) {}
}

$t2 = microtime(true);

printf("DONE!\n");
printf("Time elapsed: %.5f \n", $t2 - $t1);

// =============================------------===============================

printf("Benchmarking speed with array_intersect...");

shuffle($numbers);
shuffle($numbersLetters);

$t1 = microtime(true);

array_intersect($numbers, $numbersLetters);

$t2 = microtime(true);

printf("DONE!\n");
printf("Time elapsed: %.5f \n", $t2 - $t1);
```

**Output**

```
Sample size: 12288 elements in 2 arrays (24576 total) 
Benchmarking speed in foreach + in_array() scenario... (this might take a while) DONE!
Time elapsed: 3.79213 
Benchmarking speed with array_intersect...DONE!
Time elapsed: 0.05765
```

Fiddle: http://ideone.com/OZ2Idf

### Conclusion

`array_intersect` is much faster than `foreach` + `in_array`.

## Why is `array_intersect` faster?

- The intersection is computed in C code, as opposed to PHP
- Internally, Zend engine [sorts the array](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/23772d5b70c2628be1ecd4358b4336982911b4e9/ext/standard/array.c#L4099) prior to computing the intersection ([why is processing a sorted array faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array))

Comment: Update including https://codedmemes.com/lib/best-performance-array-intersection/ would be nice here

Comment: Fast forward to PHP 8.2 and the difference is a small order of magnitude greater still. `foreach + in_array()`: 5.11544, `array_intersect`: 0.01294.