# whats the difference between $a = (true === !!array_intersect(['1'],[3,2,1])); and checking with in_array

Tags: php, arrays, logic

When to use this:-

```
$a = (true === !!array_intersect(['1'], [3, 2, 1]));
```

and when to use this

```
$b = in_array('1', [3,2,1]);
```

Both returns same.

Comment: Actually, this is normal. Because array_intersect returns a value if there is a intersect. According to your code, this value is 1. The value is `true`as logical. So, your code being like this: `!!true`. Result of this, `true`.
in_array method return bool value directly. 
So, the both codes return same value for your codes.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? `$b = in_array('1',[3,2,1]);` - simple & easily readable.

Comment: Why this question is down voted? It is quiet interesting

Answer (score 2):

[**array_intersect()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) returns the common elements form both array. In your code `array_intersect(['1'], [3,2,1])` the returns `[1]` and when use `!!` then it's value is true. Because:

- `![1]` is `false`
- Again `!false` gets `true`

Finally `(true === !!array_intersect(['1'], [3,2,1]))` return `true`, because both sites are `true`. Note: `===` is used to check strictly (with type). That means the value of `$a` is `true`.

Second part of code:
[**in_array()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is used to check weather an element is exist or not in an array. In your code `in_array('1',[3,2,1]);` is `true` because `1` is exist in array `[3, 2, 1]`

---

The difference between `array_intersect()` and `in_array()` are:

- `array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)` return an array which are common in both array `$arr1` and `$arr2`
- `in_array($elm, $arr)` returns a Boolean (true or false) based on the existence of `$elm` in the array `$arr`

---

Since both parts of your code are getting logically `true`, that's why you are getting the same value `true`.

Answer (score 0):

**in_array** is much more readable compared to the **array_intersect** version of the same. However, **array_intersect** is much [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329211/php-array-intersect-efficiency) compared to **in_array**. So to answer your question, use **array_intersect** only if you are dealing with a data set large enough to raise performance issues. Otherwise sticking to **in_array** will make *life easier for the next developer*. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Both are different things.

**array_intersect Compare the values of two arrays**, and return the matches:

```
$a1=array(0=>"red",1=>"green",2=>"blue",3=>"yellow");
$a2=array(0=>"red",1=>"green",2=>"blue");

$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

Output will be

> Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue )

**in_array is for check if the value exists or not.**

```
$a1=array(0=>"red",1=>"green",2=>"blue",3=>"yellow");

in_array('red',$a); //true
in_array('black',$a); //false
```

Now, If you want to check the **value is exists** in an array then you may use **in_array** it'll return true or false, Or if you want get **matches** value from two array then you may use **array_intersect**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the same though. From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

> **Note**: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

So, when using `array_intersect()`, you will always get `true`, but only because the string representation of your second array element "1" matches that of the array you intersect it with. With `in_array()`, you can have a third argument, `strict`, which is a boolean to indicate whether to also use type checking ([see here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)). So, in your second example, you also have the option of checking whether the type matches, which is more fine-grained.

Personally, I would use the second option in any case just for its readability.

If you want to find elements in an array and get a subarray, then you should go for `array_intersect()` for performance reasons see [accepted answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331407/php-in-array-vs-array-intersect-performance)