# remove duplicate value and compare two array and find total same words in php

Tags: php

i have 2 array :
First is:

```
Array ( [0] => प्रतिशत [1] => से [2] => क [3] => गलती [4] => करें [5] => करें। )
```

Second is:

```
Array ( [3] => प्रतिशत [4] => से [6] => गलती [7] => करें। [13] => से [21] => करें। )
```

after  compare i want this result:

```
Array ( [0] => प्रतिशत [1] => से [2] => गलती [3] => करें। [4] => करें। )
```

please help me.

```
<?php

$clean1 = array(); 
$clean2 = array(); 
foreach($words2 as $key => $value) { 
    if($value != $result[$key]) { 
        echo "-".$clean1[$key] = $value; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: my code is: $clean1 = array();
$clean2 = array();    

foreach($words2 as $key => $value)
{
    if($value != $result[$key])
    {
        echo "-".$clean1[$key] = $value;
         
    }
}

Comment: Add your code inside your question itself.

Comment: sorry i forgot this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php array\_intersect() efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329211/php-array-intersect-efficiency)

Comment: Use `array_intersect`. Answers  have codes to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As far I have understood your question, you need to merge two arrays and have unique values in the result array.

```
$result = array_unique (array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

This will give an array with unique values merged from two given arrays.

Comment: by this repeated words also remove.  then करें। count only 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i font my ans.

```
    $words1= explode(" ", $string1);
    $words2= explode(" ", $string2);
    $result = array_intersect($words1, $words2);
     
    
    $clean1 = array();
    $array_a = $words2; // assume this is your first array
    $array_b = $result; // assume this is the array you wan to compare against
    $found = false;
    
    foreach ($array_a as $key_a => $val_a) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($array_b as $key_b => $val_b) {
           if ($val_a == $val_b) {
                   $clean1[$key_b] = $val_b;
                    break;
                   $found = true;
            }     
        }
        if (!$found){}
    }
    return count($clean1);
```